# Rewrite existing xls files using Perl

Tags: perl, excel, file-handling, xlsx

I am trying to write data in excel files which is already exists, but the code  I tried is creating a new sheet and erasing the old sheet with the data. This the code I use

```
#!/usr/bin/perl –w
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

# Create a new Excel file
my $FileName = 'Report.xls';
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($FileName);

# Add a worksheet
my $worksheet1 = $workbook->add_worksheet();  #<- My Doubt



# Change width for only first column

$worksheet1->set_column(0,0,20);

# Write a formatted and unformatted string, row and column
# notation.
$worksheet1->write(0,0, "Hello");
$worksheet1->write(1,0,"HI");
$worksheet1->write(2,0,"1");
$worksheet1->write(3,0,"2");    `
```

How can I assign the current sheet to `$worksheet1`. And one more thing is I need to read specific cell from which is already exist.
Please give me some guidance .Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You cannot open an existing a spreadsheet with [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel) and update it like that. You first want to open it using [Spreadsheet::ReadExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet%3a%3aReadExcel) along with an output sheet which you open with `WriteExcel`. Then, you read the input file, write out existing cells, sheets etc, and make whatever edits/updates/insertions you are going to make. Then, you can close both files, remove the previous, and rename the new one (optionally backing up the previous version).

You can only really edit/change a given Excel file without going through this process by opening it using [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aOLE), but for that you are most certainly going to need to be on a Windows system (I am not sure about the state of Wine), and this is not something you want to do on a server.

You can think of creating a file with `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` as similar to opening a file with `open my $fh, '>', 'output.file'` ... `output.file` **will** be clobbered.

Note the line:

> ```
> my $fh = FileHandle->new('>'. $self->{_filename});
> ```

in `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Workbook->new`.